# How to convert HTML to PDF accurately, with some CSS3 style support?

Tags: linux, pdf, html, css

I have an HTML file with CSS3 style, which I want to "accurately" convert to PDF, that's say print all styles which I cannot do with Firefox and Opera, all output PDF lost some styles(shadows or background).

I use `nth-child` to show different background color like below, and that is very important to my article:

```
li:nth-child(2n) {
    background: #eee;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
}
li:nth-child(2n-1) {
    background: #ddd;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try WkHtmlToPdf. http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

wkhtmltopdf is an open source (LGPLv3) command line tool to render HTML into PDF using the Qt WebKit rendering engine.

Comment: I install wkhtmltopdf from repository, it works well. thanks.

Comment: I made a simple GUI to help run wkhtmltopdf: https://github.com/skylogic004/wkhtmltopdf-GUI